# Synapse workspace deployment@2 error: missing required argument 'factoryId'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to use 'Synapse workspace deployment' from the Marketplace to deploy Synapse workspace from Dev to Acc to Prd. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureSynapseWorkspace.synapsecicd-deploy

But I'm getting an error:

*Command :  node D:\a\1\s\downloads\main.js export "D:\a\1\s\Synapse" syn-dwh-acc ExportedArtifacts*

*Stderr:  error: missing required argument 'factoryId'*

```
jobs:
    - deployment: deploymentjob${{ parameters.env }}
      displayName: Deployment Job ${{ parameters.env }} 
      environment: Deploy Synapse to ${{ parameters.env }}

      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            ###################################
            # Check out repository to agent
            ###################################
            - checkout: self
              displayName: '1 Retrieve Repository'
              clean: true 

            ###################################
            # Show environment and treeview
            ###################################
            - powershell: |
                Write-Output "Deploying Synapse in the ${{ parameters.env }} environment"
                tree "$(Pipeline.Workspace)" /F
              displayName: '2 Show environment and treeview Pipeline_Workspace'

            - task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
              inputs:
                operation: 'validateDeploy'
                ArtifactsFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Synapse/'
                azureSubscription: 'DevOps'
                ResourceGroupName: 'rg-syn-acc'
                TargetWorkspaceName: 'syn-dwh-acc'
                DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: true
                DeployManagedPrivateEndpoints: false
                FailOnMissingOverrides: false
                Environment: 'prod'
                npmpackage: 'prod'
```

We want to use the operation **ValidateDeploy** because that should allow you not to use the pubish button in synapse and not the branch workspace_publish in devops, but instead use the json files from the collaboration branch. (Just like the node.js deployment from Data Factory)

[image]
[image]
[image]

I already tried to add the factoryid manually to the YAML but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ArtifactsFolder property contains the correct path and doesn't end with a /
https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2022/10/synapse-error-missing-required-argument.html